# Which part of visual studio project do I submit?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exe

I need to submit a program that I have written in visual studio. The receivers asked for a visual studio solution which they could build and run. It's a WPF project.

Currently I have just zipped up the project folder. But when I try to send this over e-mail it refuses to send it because it has an .exe file.

Comment: Remove all executables. As long as they have the code.. they can build it themselves (thus producing an executable themselves).

Comment: Clean the solution before zip and send it over.

Comment: So if I go into the /bin/debug/ folder and delete all executables there, it should still be fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `Bin` and `Obj` folders in your solution and zip it..

Answer (score 1):

Send everything except the `bin` and `obj` folders, which contains the executable and temporary binary files. The executable can be rebuilt from the source and doesn't need to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that there are no applications or dlls which can be detected by email antivirus. You can get rid of these by deleting them manually (usually the bin and obj folders) or by cleaning your solution (right click on the solution and choose clean).

You may find this harder if the program has external dependencies (if this is the case you'll need to speak with your examiners to ensure they also have the required DLLs - a Pen Drive or FTP may be your best option).

Then zip and send the entire **Solution**, your assessors will probably need more than the individual project.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the solution bin and obj folder and zip it up. All done

Answer (score 0):

To remove executable files you have some cleaners to ex: VS Project cleaner. Try this to clean your project before zip.
-ravi

Answer (score -2):

you give the zip a password like 123456 then the email progam cant see the .exe file.